# How do I update two tables in a single method?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have a KendoUI Grid in my MVC Application.  The grid shows related data via a view in my SQL database.  The two tables that it shows are `Cars` and `Bookings`

**Table: Cars**

- public int Id
- public string Reg
- public string Make
- public string Model

**Table: Bookings**

- public int Id
- public DateTime BookingStart
- public DateTime BookingEnd
- public int Car_Id

The code for the grid is as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.ViewModels.CarBookings>()
.Name("Bookings")
.Columns(columns => {
    columns.Bound(c => c.Id);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Car_Id);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Reg);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Make);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Model);
    columns.Bound(c => c.BookingStart).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
    columns.Bound(c => c.BookingEnd).Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}");
    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(250);
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Groupable()
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => {
        model.Id(p => p.Id);
        model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);
        model.Field(p => p.Car_Id).Editable(false);
    })
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetBookings", "Bookings"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateBooking", "Booking")))
))
```

We allow the user to leverage the inline editing features of the grid and update details.  The problem I have is that these details are actually from two tables, so when they come to save those changes I need a way to update both the tables with the data the user changes.

Here is the `UpdateBooking` method with a very crude attempt to update both tables.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UpdateBooking([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Car car, Booking booking, CarBookings vm)
{
    unitOfWork.CarRepository.Update(car);
    unitOfWork.BookingRepository.Update(booking);
    unitOfWork.Save();
    return Json(new[] { vm }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the `Booking` Id is being referenced from the `Car` Id.  So it' won't work.  Can anyone assist with a better approach to handling this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions for this situation.

**Solution 1:** Write a SQL statment that update your database directly without going through UnitOfWork. I don't recommend this way because this case is not so special to do so. Your UnitOfWork *should* handle this.

**Solution 2:**

*Step 1:* Inside your UnitOfWork try to get the newly added Car Id.
*Step 2:* Update your Booking object with your Car Id.
Example code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UpdateBooking([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Car car, Booking booking, CarBookings vm)
{
    int carId = unitOfWork.CarRepository.Update(car);
    booking.Car_Id = carId;
    unitOfWork.BookingRepository.Update(booking);
    unitOfWork.Save();
    return Json(new[] { vm }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

Since you ask me how to update only the data that is changed. I will give you steps to do that.

*Step 1:* Get the object from the UnitOfWork.
*Step 2:* Update properties that was updated.
Example code: In this example updatingBooking is the object that contains only the fields to update (fields that have new value), some if it's fields can be null, bookInDb is the object from current database (contains old value).

```
public void UpdateBooking(Booking updatingBooking)
{
    **INIT UNIT OF WORK**
    Booking bookingInDb=unitOfWork.BookingRepository.Find(updatingBooking.Id); 
    //updatingBooking.Id might be null, you need to pass the Id of the row you want to update
    bookingInDb.BookingStart=updatingBooking.BookingStart;
    //We update only BookingStart but not BookingEnd or Car_Id
    unitOfWork.BookingRepository.Update(bookingInDb);
    unitOfWork.Save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this example @Red-Wei, is there any way to have it update only the data that is changed?  Since I don't pull all the fields to the grid, the model that passed to the controller contains nulls where there are actually values int he DB.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please feel free to ask me if you want to.